# How can I get my MUI Typography component to render a custom image cursor on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I tested setting the cursor to `cursor: pointer` which works fine, but I would like to use a custom image as a cursor. The image is stored in my src folder and I tried it in the public folder as well. I'm assuming I'm messing something up with the sytnax on `"url(JavaScript-logo.png)"`

```
import logo from "../assets/logo1.png";
...
  <Typography
        sx={{
          "&:hover": { cursor: `url(${logo}), auto` },
        }}
      >
        ["JavaScript",
  </Typography>
```

I have also tried it without the `&:hover`, and without `auto`

Comment: Have you imported the image yet? See this guide [Adding Image](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your image. You need to take a look at that. Below is the sample code(similar to yours) which I used and it worked. I have used proper-sized `svg`. You can replace it with `png` too.

```js
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Typography
          variant="h4"
          sx={{
            "&:hover": {
              cursor: `url(${CustomCursor}), pointer`,
            },
          }}
        >
          JavaScript
        </Typography>
      </header>
    </div>
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wandering-field-3z4w3f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C3-20%2C11)***

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the issue was that the image dimensions I was using were too large so I reduced the dimensions and everything works perfectly.